# Is Bootstrap fully integrated into Blazor and ready to use "out of the box", or do I need to configure my project in order to fully utilize Bootstrap?

Tags: .net, bootstrap-4, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am very new to C#, .NET, and Blazor and am having trouble figuring out how the whole ecosystem works.

From what I understand now, Bootstrap is included in a default, new, "out of the box" Blazor project, but I cannot seem to get anything but the Bootstrap styling to work.

I have been trying to get Bootstrap tooltips and drop-downs to work, but the Bootstrap CSS appears to be the only thing working for me ... JavaScript does not appear to be "working".

So, should I be able to use all of Bootstrap's functionality without any additional configuration, or is there more I need to do? If there is more, can you recommend any resources?

Comment: I believe only the Bootstrap CSS is included by default. For full Bootstrap you would need the JS file(s) and jQuery.

Comment: @Lex Do I do that "manually" or is there some NuGet command or some-sort that I need to run?

Comment: There may be a Bootstrap NuGet package that will work, but I've never used anything beyond the CSS in my Blazor apps. There are also several NuGet packages specifically for introducing Bootstrap-like functionality in Blazor. Blazorise.Bootstrap and BlazorStrap are just two examples.